# Debugging ppc binary on OS X 10.6 — gdb error: Don't know how to run

Tags: xcode, macos, gdb, powerpc

I have an old PowerPC Binary which runs on my system (Snow Leopard intel) using Rosetta. I wanted to debug the binary using GDB, however it tells me that it doesn't know how to run it. I think this may be because GDB only supports x86 binaries? I'm using the `gdb` which is supplied with the XCode environment supplied with the Mac OS X CD.

I searched and found one person with the same issue, but no answers. Do I have to install a special `gdb`?

Answer (score 1):

`gdb` on OS X is actually a wrapper script which gives you options to run `gdb` itself under Rosetta.

Try something like `gdb --translate --arch ppc ...`.  (I don't have Rosetta installed here and don't want to install it, so I can't test it easily.)

Comment: thank you, but that actually does not work - however i figured out the way it is supposed to work: http://www.extinguishedscholar.com/wpglob/?p=319 - however the app i want to debug is a CFM app - so you have to actually debug CFM with this LaunchCFMApp /<path>/<your_application>.app/Contents/MacOS/<your_application> - however herein lies my problem, this app launches another app with LaunchCFMApp which cannot be directly invoked, and im unable to attach gdb to a running LaunchCFMApp process - moreover as far as i read - you cannot even debug/breakpoint CFM apps anyway

Comment: I believe that's correct, you can't set breakpoints on CFM apps in Rosetta. Your best bet, short of a physical PowerPC Mac, is to run OS X in an emulator like SheepShaver.

Answer (score 0):

The only sensible solution I could think about might be [GDB for CW](http://xsym4gdb.sourceforge.net/).
I doubt it is still worthwhile, though.